# Excel search for empty cells, check conditions, write text

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have been doing some basic VBA programming in Excel 2010 but I have been struggling with this challenge for some time.  Basically, I have a sheet that is formatted like this (It actually has 62 columns and rows=# of days in the given month):

[image]

Column A will be hidden but is used in a few formulas.
Row 15 shows whether or not the station is open 24/7(all) or only Monday-Friday(M-F).
the values presented are arbitrary counts.  However, a blank count represents a problem unless... the station is M-F and

I need to get my code to identify a station that is open M-F and then fill in any particular Sat. or Sun (for that station) with the word "closed." then search for the next station that is M-F and repeat the process.

Initially I was having my code start with an actual value and then use several activecell.offset functions to find empty cells and then check conditions but I couldn't get it to work out.  Then I tried to check from the station name or the schedule row but I couldn't get the multiple if/nested offset statements to work either.

I would really appreciate any help or insight you could provide that would show me the best approach.  I don't really need the code that does it I just need a pseudo code walk-through unless you are kind enough to write out the code.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If I follow correctly, row 15 wont always be row 15 due to more days of the month being shown.  Is this cell 'named'?  Will it ever be something other than M-F or all?

Comment: It won't be row 15, that is just the example I created. It is and always will be row 40 and it will be hidden once the calculations are completed.  The only other thing that it could be would be closed, which would then need to fill in closed for all the cells.

Comment: Do you have a table, or list of all stations that are m-f? or atleast can you give us what determines if a station is supposed to me m-f?, or are you assuming if theres a blank on saturday and on sunday, then that station is m-f? This could cause issue if a 24/7 station was down saturday and sunday even if it wasn't supposed to wouldn't it?.

Comment: I do have a table that lists out all of the stations and the hours (it's a static table that doesn't change).  In the example, row 15 is a VLOOKUP function to return the hours. it is a simple table with station name in column A and hours in column B.  It resides on a hidden worksheet in the main workbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem I worked out before. I modified it to your spreadsheet:

```
Dim d As Long, s As Long
d = 1 'weekdays column
s = 40 'status row

Dim r As Long, c As Long
r = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, d).End(xlUp).Row
c = ActiveSheet.Cells(s, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Dim i As Long, cell As Range
i = 0

Dim days() As Long
For Each cell In Range(Cells(1, d), Cells(r, d))
    If cell.Value = "Sat" Or cell.Value = "Sun" Then
        ReDim Preserve days(i)
        days(i) = cell.Row
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next cell

For Each cell In Range(Cells(s, 1), Cells(s, c))
    If cell.Value = "M-F" Then
        For i = LBound(days) To UBound(days)
            Cells(days(i), cell.Column).Value = "closed"
        Next i
    End If
Next cell
```